# Purging tasks in Mongodb broker

Tags: mongodb, celery

I am using celery 3.0.13 and using mongodb as the broker.

I am trying to purge the tasks in a custom queue. I stopped all the workers and I tried to purge waiting tasks in the custom queue using the "celery purge" command but the command reports that no tasks were purged. I rechecked that the tasks are still in the queue even after running the commands (using flower).

Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to this issue:

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1047